# I need a synonom for the phrase "took place"

Tags: synonyms

My sentence says

"Tom Robinson's case..."

I wanted to say "took place" but I'm using it in the sentence right after it. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might use "occurred", "happened" or "simultaneously occurred or happened". Simultaneously took place is a little awkward (but understandable).

Comment: Can you explain how you'd use _simultaneously_ here? It's the odd one out, the only adverb in a list of verbs: _took place_, _occurred_, _happened_.

Comment: Sorry. Simultaneously (occurred happened or) took place.

Comment: All clear.  Maybe edit the answer then?

Comment: @DanielHarbour I did. Contemporaneously.